# MIME header appering in message body with PHP Mailer

Tags: php, character-encoding, header, phpmailer

I've been trying out the PHPMailer sample script as given in its README file. Now, when I run that script:

```
<?php
require("phpmailer.inc.php");

$mail = new phpmailer;

//$mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->From = "from@email.com";
$mail->FromName = "Mailer";
//$mail->Host = "smtp1.site.com;smtp2.site.com";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->AddAddress("someone@someplace.com");
//$mail->AddAddress("ellen@site.com");   // name is optional
$mail->AddReplyTo("info@site.com", "Information");
$mail->WordWrap = 50;    // set word wrap
//$mail->AddAttachment("c:\\temp\\js-bak.sql");  // add attachments
//$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/11-10-00.zip");

$mail->IsHTML(true);    // set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body = "This is the message body";
$mail->Send(); // send message
?>
```

I get the following warning :

> Warning: mb_send_mail() [function.mb-send-mail]: Unsupported charset
>   ""iso-8859-1";" - will be regarded as ascii in
>   /export/opt/samplefiles/phpmailer.inc.php on line 162

and the message that is received contains the header as well:

> Mime-Version: 1.0 This is the message body

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I've actually been using an older version of PHPMailer (version 0.89 or something). I've gotten myself a newer 5.2 and it appears resolved. Thanks anyway :P

Answer (score 0):

That first warning hints at [`mb_send_mail()`](http://php.net/mb_send_mail) being used over the ordinary [`mail()`](http://php.net/mail) function. Which is unlikely to be prepared for in the `PHPMailer` package.

It's the setting [`mbstring.func_overload`](http://php.net/mbstring.overload) you have to watch out for.  It shouldn't have bit zero set. (For example change `5` to `4`  -- or from seven to six,-- or for example from `3` to `2`.)

It has to be set in the `php.ini` or `.user.ini`. Function overloading can't be fixed at runtime.

If that's not adaptable then a workaround might be [`mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`](http://php.net/mb_internal_encoding) to eschew the error message, after applying [`mb_encode_mimeheader()`](http://php.net/mb_encode_mimeheader) on supplied values. Likely you have to adapt PHPMailer to omit the quotes around charaset parameters however.